# Apple HealthKit: cant get rid of "There is data saved in Health" alert when deleting the app

Tags: ios, healthkit

Our app used to support HealthKit. We do not anymore. I have reverted everything, including renewing the provisioning profiles for the updated Identifiers. However, we cannot get rid of the following alert when deleting the app[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Delete any data you added into the Health app

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution that, codewise, and without any user action, fixes this. As @loremimpsum suggests, it has to be done manually on Settings/Privacy and security/Health/Deleted apps. If you delete the synced data from there, next time you remove the app will not show such alert.